# clicking a button via javascript does not cause a post

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="fooForm">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function FooMethod() {
                alert('hello');
            }
            var fooButton;
            var fooForm;
            var fooDialog;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                InitializeVariables();
                InitiliazeDialog();
                InitiliazeForm();
            });
            function InitializeVariables() {
                fooButton = $('#fooButton');
                fooForm = $('#fooForm');
                fooDialog = $('#fooDialog');
            }
            function InitiliazeDialog() {
                var dialogOpenMethod = function () {
                    fooDialog.dialog('open');
                    return false;
                };
                var submitMethod = function () {
                    fooButton.unbind('click', dialogOpenMethod);
                    fooButton.click();
                };

                fooDialog.dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Ja': submitMethod,
                        'Nein': function () {
                            fooDialog.dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });

                fooButton.bind('click', dialogOpenMethod);
            }
            function InitiliazeForm() {
                fooButton.button();
                fooForm.submit(function () {
                    alert('doing a submit');
                });
            }
        </script>
        <input type="submit" id="fooButton" value="submit it!" onclick="FooMethod();"></input>
        <div id="fooDialog">
            Dialog info
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**what am i doing?**
i want a modal-confirmation: user clicks on button, confirmation "do you really want to...?", user clicks "yes", this click unbinds the original click-handler and clicks the button again (which should cause a submit).

**what/why is not working?**
indeed you need a special case. this demo won't work, unless you set `modal: false`.
interesting to mention: the original handler (`onclick="FooMethod();"`) is called in modal and non-modal dialog.

**EDIT:**
i adapted my sample due to [graphicdivines answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035911/clicking-a-button-via-javascript-does-not-cause-a-post/3036654#3036654), to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="fooForm" method="POST" action="">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var fooButton;
            var fooForm;
            var fooDialog;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                InitializeVariables();
                InitiliazeDialog();
                InitiliazeForm();
            });
            function InitializeVariables() {
                fooButton = $('#fooButton');
                fooForm = $('#fooForm');
                fooDialog = $('#fooDialog');
            }
            function InitiliazeDialog() {
                var dialogOpenMethod = function () {
                    fooDialog.dialog('open');
                    return false;
                };
                var submitMethod = function () {
                    fooButton.unbind('click', dialogOpenMethod);
                    fooButton.click();
                };

                fooDialog.dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Ja': submitMethod,
                        'Nein': function () {
                            fooDialog.dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
                var dialogZ = fooDialog.dialog('option', 'zIndex');

                fooButton.bind('click', dialogOpenMethod);
            }
            function InitiliazeForm() {
                fooForm.submit(function () {
                    alert('doing a submit');
                });
            }
        </script>
        <input type="submit" id="fooButton" value="submit it!" style="z-index: 9999;"></input>
        <div id="fooDialog">
            Dialog info
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**why?**
as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035911/clicking-a-button-via-javascript-does-not-cause-a-post/3037133#3037133), there's a nasty z-index-checker which i tried to avoid. but it wont' work.

Comment: opening a ticket sounds a `little` bit **overhasty** ? Why are you so sure the error is not on your side?

Comment: because i've been struggeling with this fault since 2 months, i've isolated the problem in this example to **NO** relevant '3rd-party'-code except jQuery... *did you* have a look at my example? can you tell me any failure in this basic script, or are you just commenting this a little bit *overhasty*?

Comment: Instead of fooButton.unbind('click', dialogOpenMethod);                    fooButton.click(); in submitMethod function try to do just fooForm.submit();

Comment: What does this line do: 

fooButton.button();

Comment: @graphicdivine: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/

Comment: @Sergei: because at the end of the day, it is a `.aspx`-file, where i need to catch the explicit causer of the post, to do some server-side logic

Comment: I guess I don't get it or I'm off here. You call `.unbind()` which removes the eventhandler and you are wondering why you can't call it afterwards?

Comment: @jAndy: have you tried my example?? it's `type="submit"`. so in non-modal-mode, it causes a post - in modal-mode nothing happens!

Comment: +1 for a well asked question with a robust test case

Comment: @jandy by passing two variables to 'unbind', the second of which is the named function, only that function is unbound.

Comment: This looks similar, but probably unrelated.  ?

Comment: @graphicdivine what do you mean?

Comment: @andreas-niedermair sorry, forgot my link. This: http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4544

Comment: @graphicdivine ah, interesting ... but, sry, this is unrelated. this would have been the 'solution' from Sergei

Comment: You're absolutely right, this does seem to be a bug in `modal`. Why do you need `modal=true`? What does it do?  According to http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#options "other items on the page will be disabled".  Can you simply use the dialog without this option?

Comment: @graphicdivine: i need it to prevent the user clicking eg. "save", as this button is exposed on an edit-screen ... not that simple :(

Comment: I retract that, I don't think this is a UI modal bug at all.  I think this is as-documented.

Comment: @graphicdivine: could you elaborate?

Comment: See my answer below: close the dialog first to re-enable the submit.

Comment: I don't understand why you are messing around with the z-index.  In your new code you are still not closing the dialog.

Comment: @graphicdivine: i'm not really able to close the dialog, as at the end of the day, the 'yes'-button turns into a spinner and all other buttons get removed (as there could be some server delay). the only way to avoid the prevention is to set the z-index properly

Comment: There are other ways to achieve this, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that you need to close the dialog, before you re-click the submit.  Since `modal` disables everything on the page, the dialogue must be closed or the submit is not clickable.  So your submit method becomes:

```
var submitMethod = function () {
    fooDialog.dialog('close'); // add this line ==============
    fooButton.unbind('click', dialogOpenMethod);
    fooButton.click();
};
```

Comment: well, the submit will work, but it won't cause the submit-event of the form to be triggered.

Comment: also: why for god's sake is the inline-eventHandler triggered if modal is used

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not specifying HTML form method? The default form method is GET.
So you should have:

```
<form id="fooForm" method="post" action="">
```

Action can be something else, it depends on what URL your submission handling logic is.

**Edit**:
Also instead of clicking the submit button, just submit the form directly.

```
fooDialog.dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Ja': function() { $('#fooForm').submit(); },
                        'Nein': function () {
                            fooDialog.dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: thanks for this hint, but you may try it yourself - just adapt my example ... and nope, this won't help!!

Comment: cannot submit the form, due to needing the explicit causer of the post ... i've mentioned that in a cmt!!